# Angular-CLI - how do I store connection strings in a json file?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I currently have a config file created in json which is picked up in my code as shown below. This works great using ng serve but when I build the project to production: ng build -prod The code can't access the config file.
Is there a way i should be storing configs in json using the angular-cli?

API call:

```
 this.http.get('/assets/app-config.json')
                .map(res => res.json())
                .catch((error: any): any => {
```

Json config:

```
{
 "apiUrl": "",
 "debugging": true
}
```

Comment: Actually that should work. How are you serving the output? It might be a server configuration problem.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at the file **angular-cli.json**

In the *environments* section you should find something like

```
  "environments": {
    "source": "environments/environment.ts",
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
  }
```

whatever you have specified in the "prod" property is the file that gets read when you build for production.

I hope this helps